# Long trailing "firefronts" showing up on NASA's FIRMS map, looking a bit like rocket launches. Is this a known error?

Tags: nasa

I don't work in GIS, but I've recently become interested in satellite active fire monitoring, looking to correlate such data with the frequent pollution spikes we've been having in the city I live in. Today we had another of those spikes, so I checked the FIRMS site on a whim, and noticed this huge trail of supposed active fires originating from somewhere in Russia/Kazakhstan and stopping somewhere in my country. The path looks vaguely like a launch trajectory, or maybe a satellite's orbit.

I've only found one other mention of such an event on the Internet (as far as I could describe it properly), on r/conspiracy, [where someone noticed a similar trajectory](https://www.reddit.com/r/conspiracy/comments/ekkxhc/russian_missiles/), also in Russia.

Anyone have any idea what this could be?

[image: Screencap of the map]

Comment: Seems to be something related with the sensor and/or the detection algorithm. You can see that that line is centered on the orbit of the Suomi NPP, with Fire Radiative Power less than `1 MW`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA8E7.png

Comment: So an initial false measurement done a week earlier somehow got jammed in the data?